# MySQL Unexpected Result from "in (' ' or ' ')"

Tags: mysql, sql

**What I'm Using:** The most recent MySQL on Ubuntu 12.

**The Set Up**: Suppose I have a table "EmployeePayment" with "Name" and "Hours" for each employee.  Suppose I already have it populated with values.

**The Question:**  When I use the command

```
select * from EmployeePayment where Name in ('');
```

I get the empty set, as I'd expect.  But, when I use

```
select * from EmployeePayment where Name in ('' or '');
```

I get the entire table returned.  Moreover, if I'm picky and put in the command

```
select Name, SUM(Hours) from EmployeePayment where Name in ('' or '');
```

then it only returns whatever is the top name from the table.  What's happening with this "in" command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you need to get rid of the `or`, the proper syntax for the `in` clause uses commas to separate the possibilities, such as:

```
sql> select name from people where status in ('intelligent', 'good looking')
pax
1 row returned
```

What your current variant is doing is applying the `or` operator to give you a one-element in-list. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) for more detail.

The reason why you're only getting one row for the aggregated query is because you have no `group by` clause, so you're grouping *all* rows. Most DBMS' would then complain about having a non-aggregated column that isn't part of the grouping, but MySQL is a bit fancy-free and footloose with the rules in that regard.

It's obviously grouping over the whole table (as it should) but applying some default aggregating function to the name (which it probably shouldn't, but does according to its documentation).

This MySQL extension is covered [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) but heed the warning: MySQL can choose *any* of the myriad possible values for these non-aggregated, non-group-by columns, so it's more useful when you know that all the rows in a given group share the same value for the column.

Comment: i dont think mysql can support that much confidence

Comment: ha!  Well, this was more of an exercise for myself [I'm just starting to learn SQL] to protect again injections and learn about them.  So the "or" was my attempt at injecting.

Comment: Ah!  Related to what you've noted, if I try the same thing as you've done, but I apply "...where status in ('awesome', 0);" this also returns only the top element of my list.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively doing this:

```
select * from EmployeePayment where Name in (0);
```

The OR expression evaluates to `0`, and `WHERE Name IN (0);` returns all rows. You have to use the proper `IN` syntax as suggested in the other answers:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeePayment WHERE Name IN ('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: This sounds good, but when I try something like "select Name, SUM(Hours) from EmployeePayment where Name in (0);" it only returns the first row, not each row --- is there a reason for that kind of behavior when I'm not using select *?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `IN`, the `SUM` is forcing an implicit `GROUP BY` (you can only sum when you group).

Comment: Right, but then why should it only return the grouping for the first element?  For example, it only returns the first name and his sum of hours.

Comment: The implicit grouping is the same as grouping by all rows. Why it returns a single row I can't clearly understand or explain in a comment, but it frequently does. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Yeah, it seems that for a number of strange commands it will only return the first variable.  Thank you for the links!

Answer (score 0):

`IN` uses comma separated values, for example: `WHERE Name IN ('tim','beth')`

So try `WHERE Name IN ('','');`

But more importantly, why would you want to check where a value is empty or empty? Or was that just to get the question across?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: This was more a test in learning about injections; I just tried everything I could think of --- that came up, and I thought it was kind of unexpected!